# How to draw these diagrams?

Tags: diagrams, tikz-feynman, feynman

I am writing my Masters thesis and I need to draw some diagrams that look like this:

[image]

I have been drawing many Feynman diagrams already, but I am not completely sure if this can be drawn with the same package (tikz-feynman) or if I need something different.

Comment: Shouldn't be too difficult using TikZ. What have you tried so far?

Comment: To be honest I'm a begginer so I've just drawn some basic diagrams (e-e+ ->μ+μ-, etc). I think I could draw the first part of the diagram, but the dots appearing on the RHS make it much more complicated.

Comment: Never mind the dots for now … let's just put it that way: if you make a visible effort, people are much more inclined to help you figuring out the rest ;)

Comment: Okay, I will try to do it without the dots and post what I get. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/feynmf , which seems to provide many of the things you need. The good thing is, that even this package still is tikz. So, e.g. to create and place label notes, you still can do it. Have a look here, starting with the short intro: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf . Feel free to post your intermediary results with one question, each.

Comment: I feel I've cheated because I ended up using https://www.mathcha.io/ since I don't have a lot of time to learn all the techniques I need before the thesis deadline. However, I'm planning to learn this summer because I feel it can be really helpful, so thank you for the links!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here is one way to do it in tikz. Some remarks:

- use some constants for radii to position text around the circles
- the left circle accepts polar coordinates "as is"
- the right one needs some center and shift like: `\draw (r) to +(40:\RD) ...;`
- the - at R draws a white line on a white background, making it "invisible"
- notations are in math-mode
- `pifont` provides the bullets `\ding{108}`
- because `tikz-feynman` uses `tikz`, this diagram works fine with both

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{pifont}

% ~~~ some constants ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\RD[0]{12mm}
\newcommand\RDD[0]{8mm}
\newcommand\RDP[0]{5.5mm}

\begin{document}
    \tikz [LR/.style={shape=circle,fill=gray!40,draw=black}]{
        % ~~~ L and R ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        \node[name=l,LR] at (0,0) {L};
        \node[name=r,LR] at (2,0) {R};
        
        % ~~~ + and - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        %     + , using polar coordinates
        \node at (-26:\RDP) {$+$};
        %     trick: draw white line to node colored in black
        \draw [white] (r) to +(-154:\RDP) node [black] {$-$};
        
        % ~~~ drawing the lines ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        %     between circles, with text above
        \draw (l) -- node [above] {$\hat P_I$} (r);
        
        %     lines leaving L
        \draw (l) to (140:\RD) node [fill=white] {$\hat 1 ^-$};
        \draw (l) to (210:\RD) node [fill=white] {$n ^+$};
        
        %     lines leaving R
        \draw (r) to +(40:\RD)   node [fill=white] {$\hat 2 ^-$};
        \draw (r) to +(15:\RD)   node [fill=white] {$3 ^+$};
        \draw (r) to +(-6:\RDD)  node [fill=white] {\tiny\ding{108}};
        \draw (r) to +(-27:\RDD) node [fill=white] {\tiny\ding{108}};
        \draw (r) to +(-50:\RD)  node [fill=white] {$n-1 ^+$};
    }
\end{document}
```